# WordCount with treemap

Tags: java, regex, text-files, treemap

I am writing a program to read a text file, store in a treeMap and then print out the word frequences(wordcount) to the console. I keep getting the FileNotFoundException "I THINK" I'm pretty much almost done, with the remainder of the code. Any help, pointers, suggestions and tips would be appreciated. thx. Code Below

import java.util.*;

/**
 * 
 * @author
 *
 */

public class WordCount {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    TextFileInput take = new TextFileInput("noteFile.txt");

    String m = take.readLine();
    String [] input = m.split("[ \n\t\r,.;:!?(){}}]");

TreeMap <String, Integer> myMap  = new TreeMap <String, Integer> ();

    /**Set set = myMap.entrySet(); 
    Iterator i = set.iterator(); 
    Map.Entry <String, Integer> me; **/

    for(int f = 0; f < input.length; f++) {         
        String key = input[f].toUpperCase();
        if(input[f].length() > 1) {
            if(myMap.get(key) == null) {
                myMap.put(key, 1);
                }   
            else {
                    int value = myMap.get(key).intValue();
                    value++;
                    myMap.put(key, value);
            }
        }       
    }       
    /**while(i.hasNext()) { 
           me = (Map.Entry)i.next(); 
           System.out.print(me.getKey() + ": "); 
           System.out.println(me.getValue()); **/


    for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : myMap.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " : "+ entry.getValue());
    }

}
}
```

}

Comment: I am not sure if it is error in your question or in your real code but you have some extra `}` at the end. Also "*I keep getting the `FileNotFoundException`*" how are you running your code? In which location is your console? Where is located file you are trying to read? "*...and some others*" what are the other errors?

Comment: the located file is in the place where note files usually are. its right below the JRE system but not acually in it. I don't know what the name of the place is(sorry). I'm running my code as a Java file. I use TextFileInput to read the code in.

Answer (score 1):

TextFileInput - I am not sure about this. You can use File and Scanner to read from the file.
Give the absolute path of the file. eg. C://notepad.txt (for windows)

Moreover you are reading one line from the file. You can add it in while loop. And to print the TreeMap you can do as follows,

```
 for(String entry : myMap.keySet()) {
    System.out.println(entry + " : "+ myMap.get(entry));
}
```

And the complete code is below,

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.*;

public class WordCount {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    File file = new File("C://notepad.txt");
    Scanner scanner=new Scanner(file);

    TreeMap <String, Integer> myMap  = new TreeMap <String, Integer> ();

    while(scanner.hasNext())
    {
    String m = scanner.nextLine();
    String [] input = m.split("[ \n\t\r,.;:!?(){}}]");

    for(int f = 0; f < input.length; f++) {         
        String key = input[f].toUpperCase();
        if(input[f].length() > 1) {
            if(myMap.get(key) == null) {
                myMap.put(key, 1);
                }   
            else {

                    myMap.put(key, (myMap.get(key))+1);
            }
        }       
    }       
    }

    for(String entry : myMap.keySet()) {
        System.out.println(entry + " : "+ myMap.get(entry));
    }

}

}
```